# How run .sh script with user input from textfield in Java?

Tags: java, swing, sh, jtextfield, processbuilder

I try start .sh script with user input from txtfield.
Idea: user write parametre in txt fild. When push the button and script start with this parametre.

My code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
String valueURL;
valueURL = URLtxt.getText().toString();              
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
// -- Linux --
// Run a shell command
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c","nikto -h", valueURL,");     

try {

Process process = processBuilder.start();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
output.append(line + "\n");         
}
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
if (exitVal == 0)                                            
 {
    this.hide();
    ScanWS sws = new ScanWS() ;
    sws.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: what is the outcome of your code?

Comment: The quoting is clearly wrong. You probably want something like `processBuilder.command("bash", "-c","nikto -h \"$1\"", "", valueURL);` -- notice how the first argument after `bash -c "script; more script"` is a placeholder (it is used to populate `$0`).

Comment: But then `bash -c` is not doing anything useful here; probably simplify to `processBuilder.command("nikto", "-h", valueURL); `

Comment: outcome is start of command "nikto" with parametre -h and web url.

Comment: If i use , for example, processBuilder.command("bash", "-c","nikto -h google.com"); it work fine. But I wont put string from jtextfield from my GUI in place where google.com

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

1. An event istener is triggered in UI thread, so the processing must be *fast*. Your listener implementation waits for *an external process*, it can freeze your ui. All the process triggering and caring logic must start in a separate Thread.
2. A process is quite an old construction and it has input/output issue. A process writes something during it's work into a buffer of it's output stream and when the buffer is all filled - *the process hungs*, waiting for the output stream to make some space. 
   So, both *process.input* and *process.output* processors also must work in separate threads.